# python check and replace a number

Tags: python

I am a  beginner in python..
My data line looking like this

```
2015-04-18 10 101011
2015-04-18 10 102000 
2015-04-18 20 222222
2015-04-18 20 100000
```

if the below-mentioned character using () is 10 I want to replace it as 1
and 2 if it is 20

```
 2015-04-18 10 101011 to 2015-04-18 1 101011
 2015-04-18 20 101011 to 2015-04-18 2 101011
```

i read the each line by line

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as f:

file = f.readlines()
for each in file:
```

how will i give a if statement here...

Comment: please show us more than the start of the code. too broad.

Comment: Use regex? Split on spaces and check the second value? Check the 12th and 13th characters? Have you tried *anything?*

Comment: Your second highlighted text has 10 and 20 in parentheses, but your first highlighted text does not. Which is it? The code in your last highlighted text will not work, due to bad indentation. Your replacement of text will change the size of your file: is that what you want? What have you tried so far on this problem? Please improve your question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe annoying as hell, so annoying I posted something on meta some time ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338755/whats-better-a-question-with-no-attempt-or-with-an-unfixable-irrelevant-attemp

Comment: could there be other values in addition to `10` and `20` ?

Comment: @RoryDaulton   i put the partheses in second highlighted text for the mention purpose only..                                                                                                               what i need is 2015-04-18 20 100000 to 2015-04-18 2 100000

Comment: @sparatan please don't post irrelevant code that shows nothing of what you tried. I'd rather not see any code...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre their inclusion of irrelevant code, or my suggestion that they make an attempt *before* dumping it on SO?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that'll be the first one of course :) I don't mind about the non-attempts. I mind about the false attempts.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes   30 also...

Comment: @sparatan and 40? 50?

Comment: Then you should just show the four lines that would replace the lines you show in your example. "Highlighting" the way you did is just confusing. It is good that you show us an example of input and desired output. Some more corrections and your question will become a good one--but you still have more work to do now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no...only 10,20,30 and want to replace 1,2,3 respectively

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a possibility for this but may be overkill. Here's a solution using `split()`:

```
DATA =\
"""2015-04-18 10 101011
2015-04-18 10 102000 
2015-04-18 20 222222
2015-04-18 20 100000"""

def process_data(data):
    substitutions = {'10':'1', '20':'2', '30':'3'}
    for line in data.splitlines():
        components = line.split()
        components[1] = substitutions[components[1]]
        yield ' '.join(components)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in process_data(DATA):
        print(line)
```

**Output**

```
2015-04-18 1 101011
2015-04-18 1 102000
2015-04-18 2 222222
2015-04-18 2 100000
```

**Assumptions**

Since there are a number of details that you haven't made clear from your question, I'll list the assumptions I've made with this implementation:

- Every line of data will have at least one space in it (otherwise `components[1]` will cause an `IndexError` to be raised).
- The data following the first space will be either "10" or "20", followed by another space.
- All whitespace divisions in each line are a *single* space. `Otherwise ' '.join(components)` will yield a line with different spacing to the original.

No assumptions are made about the relationship between the inputs ("10" and "20") and their replacements ("1 and 2"). From this very small dataset, it seems like `f(x) = x/10`, but only you know for sure. You can adapt the substitution logic in accordance with your use case if necessary.

Comment: `components[1] = substitutions[components[1]]` crashes if not known. I would generalize to `components[1] += "0"`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There are a number of assumptions I've made that will crash my program if they don't hold. I wouldn't make that change just yet because you're inferring a pattern from two points of data - OP has not explicitly stated the relationship between the input and its replacement, and perhaps "30" should map to "5" instead of "3".

Comment: that's why the question isn't so "popular" :) then you should explain your hypothesis.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not a bad suggestion, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `re.sub` function with *replacement callback*:

```
def shortenDigits(m):
    d = {'10': '1', '20': '2', '30': '3'}
    val = m.group(2)
    return m.group(1) + (val if val not in d else d[val])

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()
    replaced = [re.sub(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} )(\d{2})', shortenDigits, l) for l in lines]

print(replaced)
```

The output:

```
['2015-04-18 1 101011\n', '2015-04-18 1 102000\n', '2015-04-18 2 222222\n', '2015-04-18 2 100000\n']
```

Comment: Upvoting this because my first thought was to use `re.sub` but I wasn't sure how to use it for substitutions dependent on the match itself. This taught me how.